# Samsung galaxy s4 audio static issue

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I just upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy S4 and I'm noticing a distracting static sound both in headphones and through the built in speaker.  I notice it overlaid on the audio itself but it's very faint and it doesnt really bother me.  However, it becomes distracting because whenever there is a pause and silence, right before the audio starts up again there is a burst of static leading in.

This is not much of an issue for music but where it really makes a difference is when listening to audiobooks or podcasts because every time someone pauses and starts again the static is very noticeable.

Is this a common problem?  Is it fixable? Should I just return my phone to the store for a different one?  Thanks!

Comment: What update did you do? Official or a ROM? Is this in general or on specific apps?

Comment: I didn't update the phone, I upgraded to the S4 from my old phone through at&t.  The phone is brand new.  This happens with every app I've tried including the music app that came with the phone, a podcast app and an audiobook app.

Comment: Mine isn't doing this at all, I just tried now. I'd say pop back to the shop and see if you can get a replacement. You're not the only one with this: http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-s4-headphone-issues-208838/   Try another pair of headphones before you do?

Comment: ok, thanks, I did see that article but I thought my issue was different because my static over the music isnt as bad as that and mine happens over the built in speaker as well.  I will try a different set of headphones though, just to make sure.

Comment: tried other pairs of headphones, same issue